# Comparing strings in huge lists but cannot use set in Python

Tags: python, performance, nlp, list-comprehension, string-comparison

I have a text file with 11965 entries that looks like:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD

Which I transformed into:
list_1 = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', ...]
```

And I need to compare it with another text file with 2221545 entries that looks like:

```
AAA,.ADJ UK
AAA,.N UK
AAA,.N ES
B,.ADV UK
BB,.ADV UK
BBB,.N IT

Which I transformed into:
list_2 = ['AAA\tADJ\tUK', 'AAA\tN\tUK', 'AAA\tN\tES', 'B\tADV\UK', 'BB\tADV\tUK', ...]
```

So I have to get a dict that looks like this:

```
result_dict = {'AAA':[[UK, ADJ, N], [ES,N]], 'BBB':[[IT,N]], ...}
```

Due to the size of the second list, if we compare the entries one by one the time complexity will be `O(11965*2221545)`. (Am I getting in right?)

And because I have to get the entire entry, I cannot use set to compare them. Is there any efficient way to get the job done?

Comment: "because I have to get the entire entry, I cannot use set to compare them" - why? Also, why do you need the first file? You could get your desired result just by grouping the second file by the first bit, which you can do with a `dict` (in fact, the very `dict` you cite as your target result).

Comment: Could you be more specific? I didn't understand. :)

Comment: @JoeannYen how is `'AAA':[[UK, ADJ, N], [ES,N]]` computed? If there's 3 AAA's, why are both lists not 3 elements?

Comment: @JonClements cause I need to know that given a language, for example, 'UK', the word 'AAA' can be an 'ADJ' or a 'N'.

Comment: I don't think you really want to represent the data that way? You probably want `{'AAA': {'UK': ['ADJ', 'N'], 'ES': ['N']}, 'BBB': {...}, ...}` (i.e. type `Dict[str, Dict[str, List[str]]]`). Having the first element of a list represent something different from the other elements is bad practise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there was another answer here which used a `defaultdict`. Mine goes a bit further and uses the resultant format I gave in the comments and works in linear time.

```
list_2 = ['AAA\tADJ\tUK', 'AAA\tN\tUK', 'AAA\tN\tES', 'B\tADV\tUK', 'BB\tADV\tUK']

import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(list))

for line in list_2:
    word, wordtype, lang = line.split('\t')
    d[word][lang].append(wordtype)
```

`d` is

```
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {'AAA': defaultdict(list, {'ES': ['N'], 'UK': ['ADJ', 'N']}),
             'B': defaultdict(list, {'UK': ['ADV']}),
             'BB': defaultdict(list, {'UK': ['ADV']})})
```

We can convert into a standard dict like so:

```
{k: dict(v) for k, v in d.items()}

# {'AAA': {'ES': ['N'], 'UK': ['ADJ', 'N']},
#  'B': {'UK': ['ADV']},
#  'BB': {'UK': ['ADV']}}
```

We can access a word/lang combo simply by doing

```
d['AAA']['UK']
# --> ['ADJ', 'N']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I know that using the first element of a list to represent something different from it is not a good practice, but the next step is actually using this dict to write into an .xlsx file and the fact that dictionaries are unslicable could be problematic afterwards. But I try with this dict first. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution not requiring sets:

```
result_dict = {}

for item in list_1:
    result_dict.setdefault(key, [])

for item in list_2:
    value_list = item.split('\t')
    key, values = value_list[0], value_list[1:]
    result_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(values)

print result_dict
# {'B': [['ADV\\UK']], 'AAA': [['ADJ', 'UK'], ['N', 'UK'], ['N', 'ES']], 'BB': [['ADV', 'UK']]}
```

The complexity will be linear on the lists' total length.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. Very elegant. :)

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of what I was saying in the comments. I don't see where the first file comes into play.

```
list_2 = ['AAA\tADJ\tUK', 'AAA\tN\tUK', 'AAA\tN\tES', 'B\tADV\tUK', 'BB\tADV\tUK']

from collections import defaultdict
collect_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for line in list_2:
    word, pos, country = line.split()
    collect_dict[word][country].append(pos)
result_dict = { word: [[country] + poss for country, poss in country_pos.items()]
                for word, country_pos in collect_dict.items()}
# => {'AAA': [['UK', 'ADJ', 'N'], ['ES', 'N']], 'B': [['UK', 'ADV']], 'BB': [['UK', 'ADV']]}
```

EDIT: I actually agree with FHTMitchell's comment - only do the last transformation if you really like the format you posted in the question, but the format in `collect_dict` is likely much more useful.

EDIT: based on the clarification in the comments (list 1 is used to restrict elements of list2):

```
list_2 = ['AAA\tADJ\tUK', 'AAA\tN\tUK', 'AAA\tN\tES', 'B\tADV\tUK', 'BB\tADV\tUK']

from collections import defaultdict
valid_set = set(list1)
collect_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for line in list_2:
    word, pos, country = line.split()
    if word in valid_set:
        collect_dict[word][country].append(pos)
result_dict = { word: [[country] + poss for country, poss in country_pos.items()]
                for word, country_pos in collect_dict.items()}
```

Comment: I'm guesing if the number of unique keys in the 2221545 entry file happens to be the same as the ones in the 11965 file then you wouldn't need it. However, it may be there's data not required in the larger file and the check is to ensure only the 11965 subset is ever present...

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But I would be happy if the asker actually told us this when we asked about it. "Compare" is not an actionable thing.

Comment: The reason why I wanted to "compare" these two lists is exactly because I'd only want to keep the 11965 entries. Sorry that I wasn't being specific enough. Thank you all for participating. :)